# How to use Document Properties from Sharepoint in MS Word Field Codes?

Tags: word, document-template, quick-parts

I want to use Document Properties that are passed down from a document content type from Sharepoint in IF-Statements in Word (Field Codes). The goal is to automate contract creation using a template and sharepoint data from a library.

Though within the template I want to have multiple IF-Fields to correctly change the content according to Gender etc.

My problem is that I can easily add the document properties using Quick Parts > Document Properties, but when I create a new Field code (CTRL-F9) and write:

```
{ IF { DOCPROPERTY Anrede } = "Herr" "männlich" "weiblich" }
```

it keeps returning "ERROR! Unknown document property name".

Whenever I just use Quick Parts, the information is always there and correct, so I am completely confused why it won't work with field codes.

UPDATE:
So now I tried `{ Set Anrede "[Anrede]" }` *([Anrede] being a Quick Part Document Property)*

But when I try and REF it in an IF function, like:

```
{ IF { REF Anrede } = "Herr" "männlich" "weiblich" }
```

the result doesn't change when the input does..

Thanks in advance for any help!

*I did not write the braces out by hand, but always used CTRL-F9*

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago but I have managed to use what you have posted in order to solve this exact same issue for myself.

When using {Set Anrede "[Anrede]"} I managed to make it work by swapping that to {Set Andede } then going to Quick Parts > Document Property and then selecting the property, this then allowed me to set up the IF statement.

I hope this helps even now but thank you for pointing me in the right direction to fix my problem.