# How to use Document Properties from Sharepoint in Conditional IF Statements?

Tags: sharepoint-online, word, properties, document-template, quick-parts

My question and objective are very similar to the question at this link, but unfortunately the answer didn't provide enough information for me to implement the proposed solution: [How to use Document Properties from Sharepoint in MS Word Field Codes?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269159/how-to-use-document-properties-from-sharepoint-in-ms-word-field-codes)

In SharePoint I have custom columns / properties passed from a custom Content Type to new document.

Based on those properties, I want the template to 'autofill' text (auto-insert an autotext). Sample logic:

```
If gender=female, insert paragraph1
```

I thought I could use the IF statement in MS Word's QuickParts and use DocProperty fields like so:

```
{ IF { DOCPROPERTY Gender } = "Female" {AUTOTEXT customText} "OTHER TEXT" }
```

Unfortunately, as is well documented (https://sharepains.com/2018/06/29/sharepoint-online-2016-document-properties-vs-docproperty), SharePoint custom properties aren't related to DocProperties. So the "Gender" property from SharePoint isn't accessible as a DocProperty:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

I have used VBA before, and I am open to using it if absolutely necessary. However, I wanted to avoid it so end-users don't have trouble with macro-disabled files (employees in my organization don't always remember to enable macros for internal macro-enabled documents and then tell me the templates don't work!).

Thanks in advance!

(Apologies for the large photos!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

1. Add the Gender as a Quick Part to the document.
2. Create a **Bookmark** for the Quick Part and give a name, for example, Bookmark1.
3. Use the Bookmark in the Field Codes.
   The sample code should be formatted as: `{ IF Bookmark1 ="Female" A B }`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked! Still not entirely perfect as I find myself having to press "F9" to refresh for the IF statement to take effect, but that's OK.